# how to get particular value in firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show only "uname" in my listview but I could not do it. I am getting all the data.

[image]

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("users");
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       for(DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.i("result",data.toString());

            String user =data.getValue(String.class);
            driverlist.add(user);
            Log.i("user message",user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to go deeper in your tree there. By iterating snapshot on 'users' you are getting token children. You either create a user object containing values address, email ec.. and call data.getValue(User.class), or you call data.child("uname").getValue(String.class)

Answer (score 7):

You need to use *child(fieldName)* method to retrieve exact field you want from data snapshot:

```
   for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String userName = String.valueOf(data.child("uname").getValue());
        driverlist.add(userName);
   }
```